# how to change html tag using another php/html file

Tags: php, html

I am beginner in web technology, I have html page which i want to edit from anywhere around the world, I want to make it dynamic. Please guide me with simple example. I want to use php/html to edit my intex.html page. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Comment: To make a web page dynamic you might need 3 things: 
1. Database: Store the information that might change overtime.
2. Html: Serves as a container with static content like header, footer, sidebars, etc. Inside that container you render the information that changes.
3. PHP: Makes it all work, with it you can make  a backend which you will use to update the information you stored in the database, and in turn, displays the html with the dynamic content. 

Hope it was clear enough to get an understanding, let me know if you need a more articulate example.

Comment: you can make dynamic html tags by using jquery..